# Mail merge Vista Word 2007 with Windows Live Mail

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, windows-live-mail, mail-merge

When I do a mail merge to send email from Word 2007 with Windows Live Mail installed, it doesn't seem to send the messages.  Are there known problems with Windows Live Mail for mail merge?  Is there a way around?